# how to print $HISTFILE?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to print the path of $HISTFILE in emacs, but it doesn't work with `(getenv "HISTFILE")` or `(shell-command-to-string "echo $HISTFILE")`. It is working with $PATH and every other variable I've tried.

Comment: Maybe Emacs was started within a `sh` session. To check, just launch two terminals, one under `bash`, and the other under `sh`. In every of the two terminals, type: `echo $HISTFILE`.

Comment: .. or from a desktop environment that does not set HISTFILE, so it is not in emacs's environment. OTOH, if you start a shell within emacs with `M-x shell` it will set HISTFILE, so it will be in *its* environment (but still not in the environment of emacs).

Comment: why does my arch linux not set HISTFILE, though I can echo it ? And I just found out, that `shell` also tries `(getenv "HISTFILE")` and otherwise sets it with ...`(string-equal shell "bash") "~/.bash_history")`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the bash-shell.  The HISTFILE environment variable is either set implicitly by the shell or by setting it in some script file, e.g. ~/.bashrc.

Emacs inherits the environment from the process that started it, which is usually some X-window-manager, while `shell-command-to-string` starts a non-interactive shell.

So, either there is no shell involved, or it is, but neither does it set this variable implicitly, nor does it read any initialization scripts, where it may have been set.

Comment: Is it possible to read HISTFILE somehow or do I have to set it manually ?

Comment: Try `(shell-command-to-string "bash -ic 'echo $HISTFILE' 2>/dev/null")`